# XML to JSON conversion: CDATA

Tags: c#, .net, xml, json, json.net

Am using Newtonsoft.JSON to convert XML to JSON. However, if there is any CDATA in the XML, the JSON object is not right.
For example:

```
   <CUST><First_Name>Luke</First_Name> <Last_Name>Skywalker</Last_Name> <ID><![CDATA[1234]]></ID> </CUST>
```

Am expecting something like

```
"CUST": {
    "First_Name": "Luke",
    "Last_Name": "Skywalker",
    "ID": "1234"
  }
```

but instead it returns

```
"CUST": {
    "First_Name": "Luke",
    "Last_Name": "Skywalker",
    "ID": {"#cdata-section":"802011252"}
  }
```

My code looks like..

```
var xmlDoc=new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml("<XML>"+Attributes_X+"</XML>"); 
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlDoc.OuterXml);
var cDataNodes = doc.DescendantNodes().OfType<XCData>();
  return JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlDoc,new Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting(),true);
```

How can I eliminate this issue, Should remove or encode CDATA before conversion. How can I achieve it. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Well what *code* are you using to perform the conversion? A short but complete example demonstrating the problem would really help.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have tagged it to C#, and just updated the question with small snippet.

Comment: A short but *complete* program would be better than a snippet. (Any reason you need to use `XmlDocument` instead of `XDocument`, btw? LINQ to XML is much nicer... and may well make for a much simpler answer, too.)

Comment: The reason why i have considered XmlDocument instead of XDoc is due to JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode accepts XmlNode

Comment: Yes, but `JsonConvert.SerializeXNode` accepts `XNode`...

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't notice that. Cool thanks a ton, will play around with XML to LINQ, will conside xnode. Will update the question with solution, might be helpful to someone else.

Comment: Just as a note - I am using XDocument and if serialized to JSON it's definitely doing the #cdata-section as well.

`StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(GetXml());
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(sr);
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(xDoc);`